# Oracle table SELECT rights issue

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00942

My application has few tables on Oracle where user XYZ is the schema owner. Tables has been created using XYZ. And I would like to have ABCUSER to have CRUD rights on these tables. I have given the access via `GRANT ALL ON TABLEABC to ABCUSER` and grant is succeeded.

But when this user(ABCUSER) tries to query the DB (select * from TABLEABC) it doesn't seem to work.  I get error message

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 14
```

Could you please tell what am I missing ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

User ABCUSER has privileges on the table but doesn't own it.  So you need to include the schema in the query:

```
select * from XYZ.TABLEABC
/
```

If you don't want to hardcode the schema name in your programs your user can build a synonym:

```
create synonym TABLEABC for XYZ.TABLEABC
/
```

Then the original query will work for ABCUSER.

Note that ABCUSER will require the CREATE SYNONYM privilege.

Answer (score 1):

As APC says, you are missing a SYNONYM.

You might want either a PRIVATE or PUBLIC synonym depending upon who you want to be able to view the table.

A good description of the various types and their uses is here:
http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Synonym