# Oracle new table is not accessible with only table name

Tags: oracle

I have inherited a Oracle 10.2 database witch I have to extend with new tables...

On the test database I just add table and grant select privileges to the "non root" user and it works.

I do the same on the production database and I can't select from the table. It only works if I do "select * from table_space.tablename" not "select * from tablename".

Do I have to add some kind of alias or something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle table SELECT rights issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580022/oracle-table-select-rights-issue)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need a synonym for the table.

See [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/synonyms.php) and [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2091.htm)

Also, try a `select * from all_synonyms;` first to see if a generic user is accessing the table through a synonym (as I suspect).

Comment: I knew it was something like this! Thank you very much!

Comment: If this solves your problem it would be nice to "accept" the answer ;)